# What is the best practice adding the same field to multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

I have several tables, for example:

```
news:
id | title | description
1 | This is first title of news | This is description
2 | This is second title of news | This is second description

blog:
id | title | description
1 | This is first title of blog | This is description
2 | This is second title of blog | This is second description
```

and another more than 10 tables.

I need add one field "some_state" which can have two values: 0 or 1.

So I can go by two ways:

1) add this field into each tables;

2) create new table, for example:

```
tables_some_state:
id | table_name | table_id | some_state
1 | news | 1 | 0
2 | news | 2 |1
3 | blog | 1 | 1
4 | blog | 2 | 1
...
```

and use Left Join this table to each tables in my queries.

So, what is the best practices in my case?

Comment: It's generally *bad* practice to have a column that contains a table name - this should throw a red flag when you're contemplating a database design

Comment: This is only an example. My tables fields set is more complicated. Instead of field "table_name" I use 2 fields, e.g. "component" and "element", something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add it on to the tables as long as it's a one-to-one relation (which it is here). I think generally the purpose for having something be in a separate table like that is to have a many-to-one relation.

Comment: Yes, this way is simpler for me, because it cause an editing of minimum lines of code.

Comment: I have decided to go by this way (case 1), so I can check this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Make them all one table and give them a "type" column, then add the one column to all of them:

```
posts:
id | type | title | description | status
1 | news | This is the first title of news | This is the description | 0
2 | blog | This is the first title of blog | This is the description | 1
...
```

Comment: `Single Table Inheritance` is a great trick, but it does require that the tables be pretty much identical.  That may or may not be the case for the OP - I don't think there's enough info to be sure, e.g. we may only have been shown a subset of the fields - specifically the common ones.

Comment: My field set of each tables isn't identical. Yes, I have shown only common ones.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion would be to create a new table and link columns on those other tables to it by id. This would allow some database normalization / limit database redundancy. You could eventually add more "states" later on as well. If you're using InnoDB, you can add some foreign keys as well.

Comment: I was thinking of actually creating a "state" table. IE table_state:|`StateID`|`State`|`Description`|

Comment: Oh, and add a column in each table citing the StateID? am I getting it?

Comment: @Skarlinski That was what I was trying to say, yes.